# Ext.define.measureAutoDimensions needs time

Tags: performance, extjs, grid

I am using a container with layout auto containing fourteen fixed-width grids with ~35 fixed-width columns each, and building the view needs fifteen seconds with my default data set.

Which is quite good, it's down from 21s just by changing the container's layout from vbox to auto, and from more than 40sec by setting fixed grid/column widths.

Still, this is too much. Chrome profiler tells me that:

- 31% of time is spent in "get offsetHeight", splitted euqally between "Ext.define.measureAutoDimensions", "Element.override.getHeight" and "Ext.define.calculate".
- 12% is spent in "Ext.override.getStyle"
- 9% is spent in "querySelectorAll"
- just 0.01% is spent in our custom column renderer. (lol)

Now I would like to trace down how these three performance-burners could be avoided. I thought that setting fixed row-height could help with performance, because I guess that "get offset height" would not be necessary then... just that I don't find where to set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone ever find the same problem as me, it's possibly because the layout is done many times in a row. Ext.suspendLayouts() and Ext.resumeLayouts() does the trick.